# Is the ring $R := \frac{\mathbb{Z}_2[x,y]}{(x^2+y^2)}$ finite?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory

Is this a finite ring: $R := \frac{\mathbb{Z}_2[x,y]}{(x^2+y^2)}$

If so, how to describe the elements? I know I should do some divisions to simplify the elements of $R$. Also I can write the denominator as $(x+y)^2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $x^2+y^2 = (x+y)^2$ in characteristic two, this ring admits a quotient map
$$\mathbb{Z}_2[x,y]/(x^2+y^2) \twoheadrightarrow \mathbb{Z}_2[x,y]/(x+y).$$
We can form a further quotient $\mathbb{Z}_2[x,y]/(x+y) \twoheadrightarrow \mathbb{Z}_2[x]$ by sending $x \mapsto x$ and $y \mapsto x$. (This is actually an iso, but that's not necessary to check.)

Now since $\mathbb{Z}_2[x]$ is infinite, $\mathbb{Z}_2[x,y]/(x+y)$ is infinite, so $\mathbb{Z}_2[x,y]/(x^2+y^2)$ is infinite.

Answer (score 1):

It should be pretty straightforward to observe that in the quotient, $$x^{n} \neq x^{m} \hspace{2em}\forall n \neq m \in \mathbb{N}.$$
So this ring cannot be finite.